# AngularJS - Services vs. Functions

Tags: angularjs

I am confused about when to use a service and a function in a controller to perform something . What's the difference here? Am new to AngularJS.

If the explanation could be illustrated with the scenario of registering users in a website that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean service vs factory?

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

Comment: @Filype Not really. This is what I am confused about: assume am registering a user - user fills form and post ...do I use a signup service to validate input or a function in a controller to validate? After validating, I want to post data to database, do I use function in the same controller or factory? What's the difference or what should guide me in this selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can use a function to get/send data I would use a service to deal with all of it.  Then it's simple enough to plug in any controller you like simply by calling your service and the associated getter/setter to retreive/send your data.

Comment: Aha now a bit clearer...just to confirm...I can have a function that is called signup but within that function I will utilise services to do things such as check user exist or not, create account, etc. Correct ?

Comment: Yes, so say your service is called `myService`, and within it you have a `setNewUser(data)` function, you simply add your service as a dependency to your controller and call `myService.setNewUser(data)` passing your data to your controller which can then execute a function within your service to send data to your server.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this...appreciate it